# terraform 0.12 application gateway ssl certificate issue

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

We are trying to upgrade terraform 0.11 to 0.12, and there is an application gateway ssl certificate issue.
It works fine when use like below by terraform 0.11:

```
  ssl_certificate {
    name     = "helm-mbw-int.mercedes-benz.com.cn"
    data     = "${base64encode(file("certificates/${var.helm_mbw_pfx_file}"))}"
    password = "${var.helm_mbw_ssl_certificate_password}"
  }
```

After upgarde to terraform 0.12.31 and terragrunt 0.19.0
It appears error:
Call to function "file" failed: contents of certificates/helm_mbw_pfx_file.pfx are not valid
UTF-8; use the filebase64 function to obtain the Base64 encoded contents or
the other file functions (e.g. filemd5, filesha256) to obtain file hashing
results instead

How should I update the data field? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you can try using below:

```
  ssl_certificate {
    name     = "helm-mbw-int.mercedes-benz.com.cn"
    data = "${filebase64("certificates/${var.helm_mbw_pfx_file}")}"
    password = "${var.helm_mbw_ssl_certificate_password}"
  }
```

Instead of

```
  ssl_certificate {
    name     = "helm-mbw-int.mercedes-benz.com.cn"
    data     = "${base64encode(file("certificates/${var.helm_mbw_pfx_file}"))}"
    password = "${var.helm_mbw_ssl_certificate_password}"
  }
```

Comment: OK, I'm new to use stack, should I click "Vote" for the answer?